# KerasTensor to Tensor

Tags: keras, tensor, transformer-model, image-classification

I am working on a image classification problem using a transformer model with linear self-attention.

I get a type error stating: "TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not KerasTensor"

How can I convert from KerasTensor to Tensor? This problem is with a standard MNIST dataset.

Code:

```
def create_vit_classifier2():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Augment data.
    augmented = data_augmentation(inputs)
    # Create patches.
    patches = Patches(patch_size)(augmented)
    # Encode patches.
    encoded_patches = PatchEncoder(num_patches, projection_dim)(patches)

    # Create multiple layers of the Transformer block.
    for _ in range(transformer_layers):
        # Layer normalization 1.
        x1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
        # Create a multi-head attention layer.
        attention_output = LinformerSelfAttention(
          dim = 64,
          seq_len = 49,
          heads = 4,
          k = 256,
          one_kv_head = True,
          share_kv = True
        )(x1)
        # attention_output = Padder(attention_output)
        # Skip connection 1.
        x2 = layers.Add()([attention_output, encoded_patches])
        # Layer normalization 2.
        x3 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x2)
        # MLP.
        x3 = mlp(x3, hidden_units=transformer_units, dropout_rate=0.1)
        # Skip connection 2.
        encoded_patches = layers.Add()([x3, x2])

    # Create a [batch_size, projection_dim] tensor.
    representation = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
    representation = layers.Flatten()(representation)
    representation = layers.Dropout(0.5)(representation)
    # Add MLP.
    features = mlp(representation, hidden_units=mlp_head_units, dropout_rate=0.5)
    # Classify outputs.
    logits = layers.Dense(num_classes)(features)
    # Create the Keras model.
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
    return model
```

I have tried to convert between the two such as wrapping X1 in tf.constant()